# List only categories that have products

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database with following structure:

**Categories**
 [PK]CatID
 CatName

**ProductTypes**
 [PK]TypeID
 TypeName

**Manufacturer**
 ManufacturerID
 Name

**Products**
 [PK]ProdID
 Title
 TypeID
 ManufacturerID
 IsDeleted *(bool)*
 IsHidden *(bool)*

ProductTypes are "irrelevant" for my application, but are necessary for export to another system.

I want to get a nested list with categories and the products filtered on Products.IsDeleted and Products.IsHidden
Like this

Category 1
Product.ProdID - Product.Title, Manufacturer.Name ...

Category 2
Product.ProdID - Product.Title, Manufacturer.Name ...

How to do this in the simplest way with EF

```
var catList = db.TypeIDs.Where(t => t.product.Count() > 0).Select(x => x.TypeCat).Distinct().ToList();
```

This gives me the categories, but no filtering for deleted/hidden products

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
.Where(t => t.product.Count() > 0)
```

Use

```
.Where(t => t.product.Any(u => !u.IsHidden && !u.IsDeleted))
```

Comment: Hmm. That one gives me Types that contains deleted and hidden products. That means I also get categories with no products. Obviously the .Count-version gave the same result, I just didn't notice that before.

Comment: Nevermind... had a strange config of my relations..
(database sucks, strange datatypes and stuff, next project: respinn it and do some serious cleaning)

Now I only get types with "valid" products in, but i get the "non-valid" products in those to.